# Python imaging library overlay of 1000 images

Tags: image-processing, overlay, python-imaging-library

I need to create an overlay/composite of 1000 images, all of the same size on top of each other. They all will have same level of transparency, such that any pixel which has no image in any of the 1000 images will be white while a pixel which has an image in each of the 1000 images will be black in the final overlay of 1000.

I am new to the domain and have been trying to figure out the best way of doing it. I realized one can use blend or paste(unsure about the diff between them at this point), but they take just 2 images as arguments. How can i superimpose all 1000?

Comment: Can you provide 3-4 sample images please?

Comment: So each pixel of each image is either 1/1000th white or 1/1000th black. So it had better be a 16-bit image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: no, it will be 1/1000th of the summation of all pixels. A single black pixel in an otherwise all-whites will be invisible, but 4 blacks will set that pixel to 4/1000 ~ 1, or 254 in brightness.

Comment: You need an array as large as your image size, but (supposedly the input values are bytes) with a larger store. Add each new image to this; when done, divide each value by the number of images.

Comment: @Jongware It is irrelevant now, but I actually meant *each input image* pixel contributes 1/1000th white or 1/1000th black, so we meant the same thing in effect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I decided to make the heatmap using matplotlib and numpy,instead of creating superimposed images.

Answer (score 0):

you have to loop on the 1000 images , save them in an auxiliary array and plot them in the same figure , the code is going to be like that :

```
import numpy as np
import matplolib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

img_list = 'list of name of your images '
fig= plt.figure(1)

for i in img_list:
   aux=Image.open(i)
   aux=np.array(aux)
   plt.imshow(aux)
   plt.show()
plt.imsave('name.png')
```

if it doesn't work try the same script but use in each time the new image and the overlayed image as arguments to paste like this :

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

img_list = 'list of names of your images '

i=0

background = Image.new(img_list[1].mode ,img_list[1].size)

while i < len(img_list):
   aux = Image.open(img_list[i])
   background = background.paste(aux,(0,0),aux)
   i=i+1
background.show()
```